# Slow TFS migration from on-premise to TFS online with OpsHub tool

Tags: tfs, opshub

We have a 50GB on-premises TFS collection, which we want to have migrated to TFS online. We are now using the OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility, to test with. The conversion of some separate test projects seem to work fine, so now we are trying to measure the time it will take for a full migration. It looks like the migration of all 78K changesets will take about a month. That is way too long for us. The tool is using only one Core of our 8 available Cores. I don't see other resource bottlenecks, other than the CPU (the Core in use is over 50% most of the time).
Are there any tips for a faster migration? Is there any way to speed up things?
Besides asking you all for a possible solution, I am now also trying to do several smaller migrations in parallel. As soon as I have results of that, I will share them.

Comment: How is your network speed? Isn't that a bottleneck?

Answer (score 0):

Which version you are using? 
There is performance issue with label which is fixed in version 1.0.1.005.

If your projects are independent in commit (Branch and Merge operation) then you can create migration, project wise which run parallel.

Comment: We are using version "OpsHub Integration Manager Framework-OVSMU-V1.0.1.005", so it is the most recent version.

Comment: Does that mean that if Project A is branched to Project B, it is not possible to migrate only Project B? So Project A has to be migrated first? (sounds logic, but maybe it works different)

Comment: Any update on this? We are having the same problem, with 14k changesets it will take about 18 days :S We are using version 1.0.1.008